# Torsion-free quotient $M/(A \oplus B)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $M$ be an $R$-module, with $A$ and $B$ submodules of $M$ such that $A \cap B = \{0\}$ and each of $M$, $M/A$, and $M/B$ are torsion-free. Then when is (or isn't) it the case that $M/(A \oplus B)$ is torsion-free?

For example, if $R$ is any PID and $M$ is finitely generated, then all our modules are in fact free, and we can find a basis for $M$ simultaneously extending that of $A$ and $A \oplus B$, so that $M/(A \oplus B)$ is (torsion-)free.

I can't quite think of a counterexample, though; particularly one for a very tame ring like $R = \mathbb{Z}$ would be enlightening.